# PutElasticsearchHttpRecord: Invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter

Tags: mysql, apache, apache-nifi

I am trying to fetch a specific record from Database using ***QueryDatabaseTable -> UpdateAttribute-> PutElasticSearchHttpRecord***

The ES processor is throwing ***error as Java.IO.Exception Invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter.***

**Please find attached my config. How to fix this?**
I am getting the correct result in the queue after 'UpdateAttribute' but not able to push it into ES. I have added the schema.name property to appropriate schema.
The following is the correct result i am getting in the queue after UpdateAttribute processor. **How to fix the error of Invalid character between token and delimiter?**

```
[ {
  "TimeOfDay" : "2018-09-20T18:10:36.941",
  "BMU_Debug_Pack_BlkVolt_Max2" : 4114.0,
  "BMU_Debug_Pack_BlkVolt_Max1" : 4114.0,
  "BMU_Debug_Pack_BlkVolt_Max3" : 4114.0,
  "BMU_Debug_Pack_BlkVolt_Max0" : 4116.0,
  "BMU_Debug_Pack_CTemp_Min" : 21.0,
  "BMU_Debug_Pack_CurrVolt_Curr" : 2.0,
  "BMU_Debug_Pack_Blk_Volt_Delta" : 6.0,
  "total_Difference" : 15.0
} ]
```

Thank you! Please help what should I change?

[image: QueryDatabaseTable]

[image: QueryDatabaseTable SQL]

[image: ElasticSearch]

[image: Elasticsearch Config]

[image: ES Schema]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure **Avro Reader** instead of `CSV Reader` in **PutElasticSearchHttpRecord** as `Querydatabase`Table processor outputs flowfile in **Avro format**.

Use `embedded avro schema` in Avro Reader controller service.
[image]